# Why won't my Thunderbird mail access my Yahoo mail?

Tags: thunderbird

I always get "configuration could not be verified" regardless of how many times I try to configure my T-
I have had computer software professionals try with no success.

Comment: Yahoo or Yahoo Mail Plus? See here for the difference: http://kb.mozillazine.org/Using_webmail_with_your_email_client

Answer (score 1):

What type of Yahoo account you have? ( Paid or Free).

As far as I remember FREE Yahoo account does not work except the Zimbra Desktop client.

Have you earlier configured the Yahoo account with Thunderbird and did it worked?

Comment: I downloaded the latest Zimbra I could find as per your suggestion but it didn't work. Is there something else to do after downloading , like installing maybe?

Comment: no.. it should work with normal setup. just select account type yahoo..

Answer (score 1):

I received the below answer for a similar query:

Any email client that supports IMAP (which is all of them) can be setup to use Yahoo Mail. Just use the following settings when adding a new account to your email client...

Incoming Server: imap.mail.yahoo.com
Outgoing Server: smtp.mail.yahoo.com
Incoming Port: 993 with SSL
Outgoing Port: 465 with SSL or port 587 with SSL/TLS
-It is necessary to enable SSL or TLS for Outgoing SMTP port.
Username: full email address (for example, free2rhyme@yahoo.com)
Password: the password you use to sign in to your Yahoo! Account

Answer (score 0):

using thunderbird (and as far as i am aware, all desktop email clients)you can get your mail but you  cannot send or reply to email received via a free yahoo account.

if you want complete use of your yahoo account via thunderbird, you must have a paid account.

I would suggest you set up a free account with another provider if you want proper access via thunderbird, otherwise your only option is to visit the yahoo mail page online